# ReactJs with Jest: Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a class:

```
class NumberLabel extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

....
}
export default NumberLabel;
```

And a spec in the same dir:

```
import React from "react";
import NumberLabel from "../NumberLabel.jsx"


test('test jest', () => {

const label = shallow(
    < NumberLabel params={options}>12</NumberLabel >
);
expect(label.text()).toEqual('12');
```

});

But when running the tests i get:

Cannot find module '../NumberLabel.jsx' from 'NumberLabel.spec.js'

in my package.json I have this:

```
"jest": {
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "jsx",
      "js"
    ]
  }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You mentioned that the test is located in the same directory. So eventually the import here is wrong. Please use only one point to reference the same directory.

`import NumberLabel from "./NumberLabel.jsx"`